# How do you extend backdrop-filter?

Tags: html, css, web-development-server, web-developer-toolbar

I am currently attempting to increase the width of the back-drop filler effect and I am confused on how to do it. The first picture is what I have and the second is what it should look like. I feel it possibly has something to do with increasing the width and height of my nav but when I tried it didn't work out. Could also have something to do with the fact I used absolute with the nav instead of using float but im so copnfused. Thanks.
[image: What I currently have]

[image: What I want it to look like]

This is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellefair&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Space tourism website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-logo">
    <img class="logo" src="assets/shared/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">00</span>Home</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">01</span>Destination</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">02</span>Crew</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">03</span>Technology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="description-container">
    <h5>So, you want to travel to</h5>
    <h1>Space</h1>
    <p>Let’s face it; if you want to go to space, you might as well genuinely go to
    outer space and not hover kind of on the edge of it. Well sit back, and relax
    because we’ll give you a truly out of this world experience!</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Explore</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code

```
body {
  background-image: url(assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
hr {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 9.375rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 6.25rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 4.75px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
p {
  width: 32%;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 70px;
}
.top-logo {
  margin: 53px 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > a {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.nav-number {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  right: 230px;
  background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
.description-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you're following Kevin Powell's scrimba course for this, but you should not be using floats/position absolute for the nav

Answer (score 1):

Hello i have rewrite your code to make an clean code on my  version.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper_navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo_navbar {
  display: flex;
}

.img_logo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 75px;
}
.hr_line{
  display:flex;
  flex:auto;
}


.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
  padding: 10px 17px;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

.item_nav {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_navbar">
  <div class="logo_navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://img1.pngdownload.id/20171220/dxq/google-png-5a3aafee6ff5c8.9595681415137955664586.jpg" class="img_logo" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr_line">
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="item_nav"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="item_nav"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li class="item_nav"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dimaswahyu/ntg09e5b/86/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple explanation. Every picture paints a thousand words...

[image]